# Extract data in R or Python from data file with no column headers

Tags: python, r

I have a txt file with several columns. see sample data below.

25  180701  1  12
25  180701  2  15
25  180701  3  11
25  180702  1  11
25  180702  2  14
25  180722  2  14
14  180701  1  11
14  180701  2  13

There are no column headers. Column 1 is ID, Column 2 is date, Column 3 is Hour, Column 4 is value. I am trying to look up the number 25 in column 1 and extract data for all hours during period 180701 to say 180705 all values. so the result would be a new text file with following data.

25  180701  1  12
25  180701  2  15
25  180701  3  11
25  180702  1  11
25  180702  2  14

Any help in R or Python is appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: Please post code attempt and any errors/undesired results. SO is not a code-writing service but a volunteer Q/A to help programmers who make earnest efforts. O/w read docs/online tutorials and return with specific issues.

Comment: pandas can do this in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we read the file with `read.csv/read.table`, there is an option `header=FALSE` and use `col.names`

```
df1 <- read.csv("file.csv", header = FALSE,
      col.names = c("ID", "date", "Hour", "value"))
```

and subset the values later

```
subset(df1, ID == 25 & (date %in% 180701:180705), select = 1:4)
```

Comment: Thanks, when you say ID %in% where will i specify to look for ID "25"?

Comment: @Patrick Sorry, I meant `date`.  updated it

Comment: Got it. If i have more columns in the file but i don't need them do i still need to define them in col.names? or only until the first 4 columns that i really care for?

Comment: @Patrick There is a `select` option (updated) that can either take numeric index or column names as strings

Comment: so when i use the col.names above i get error message "Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names"

Comment: also how to write.out the subset?

Comment: @Patrick  You can use `write.csv`  if `out <- subset(df1, ...); write.csv(out,  "yourfile.csv", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)`

Comment: ignore last one. i was able to write.out. still not sure how to col.names without giving a header to each and every column,.

Comment: @Patrick  If you don't have a column name in the original dataset, you need some sort of `vector` of names to name the columns.  Otherwise, how would it know what the column names you want to name.  For that, when you use `header=FALSE`, it gives default names as `X1`, `X2`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In R `readr::read_delim()` has a `col_names` parameter that you can set to `F`

```
> readr::read_delim('hi;1;T\nbye;2;F', delim = ';', col_names = F)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  X1       X2 X3   
  <chr> <int> <lgl>
1 hi        1 TRUE 
2 bye       2 FALSE
```

Answer (score -1):

```
In Python, try this:

import pandas as pd

#To read csv files without headers. use 'header = None' to be explicit

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',header = None)
df


# Then rename the generated columns
df2 = df.rename({0:'ID',1:'Date',2:'Hours',3:'Value'},axis = 'columns')
df2
```

Comment: That is a good solution on how to put names in the column headers, but that doesn't fit the question. (Which is more a "how do I write a program to do this?" question.

Comment: @RufusVS Thanks for pointing that out. I partially understood the question.